# Function parameters of the function inside a /bin/bash command

Tags: bash, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I had to use some bash code called from /bin/bash as a command followed `-c` option. I got something that is difficult to understand. This passed as expected:

```
root@punk:/home/s# function a () { echo $1 "world";}&&a hello
hello world
root@punk:/home/s#
```

But this missed the parameter of the function

```
root@punk:/home/s# /bin/bash -c "function a () { echo $1 "world";}&&a hello"
world
root@punk:/home/s#
```

How to fix the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using double quotes, with

```
/bin/bash -c "function a () { echo $1 "world";} && a hello"
```

, the current value of `$1` will be replaced which must be empty in your environment so it'll become

```
/bin/bash -c "function a () { echo "world";} && a hello"
```

which is actually

```
/bin/bash -c "function a () { echo world;} && a hello"
```

.

You can use single quotes for the outer quoting:

```
[STEP 101] # /bin/bash -c 'function a () { echo $1 "world";} && a hello'
hello world
[STEP 102] #
```